# Error while creating Kafka topic called tweets

Tags: apache-kafka

i am trying to create a topic using Kafka, and i am currently using kafka version: kafka_2.13-3.3.1.
I first started Kafka using this command:

```
bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties & bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties
```

I am currently running Kafka in a Windows Ubuntu WSL window and i am trying to create a Kafka topic like this:

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --topic tweets --from-beginning --bootstrap-server localhost:9092
```

Once i run this command i get 2 warnings, but without the command actually failing, and i do not know what is wrong. This is the warning i am getting:

```
[2022-10-11 13:52:03,869] WARN [Consumer clientId=console-consumer, groupId=console-consumer-3781] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 2 : {tweets=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2022-10-11 13:52:03,977] WARN [Consumer clientId=console-consumer, groupId=console-consumer-3781] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 4 : {tweets=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

I have looked at similar stack overflow questions regarding failing to to create the topic, but none of them seems to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consuming a topic doesn't create it.

You need to use `kafka-topics --create` first. You may also want to actually produce data into it before consuming...

Also, as of Kafka 3.3.1, you don't need Zookeeper

https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart